# Suggestions/Recommendations for a Web Application with Sub-Apps

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, architecture, mvp, wcsf

I’m starting to think about and develop an architecture for a big web application, and I wanted to get suggestions and/or recommendations on which technologies and/or frameworks to use.

The application will be an Intranet-based web site using Windows authentication, running on IIS and using ASP.NET.  It’ll need to be structured as a main web application with sub-web applications.  Essentially, the entire scope is a composite browser-based, Intranet application that is composed of discrete, functionally complete modules or sub-applications.

This composite web client application would have a main or shell module to provide the overall user interface structure.  Additionally, the shell module would provide access to common services that all the individual sub-apps or modules could use.  Then each sub-app/module would contain its own functionality and implementation, but integrate with the shell user interface.

Next, based on the user and which of the sub-apps are available, the main or shell app would dynamically build tabs (or buttons or something) as a way to access each individual application.  And, we’ll be storing the user and application data in a database table.

So, for example, we’re going to have a reports application, a display application, and probably a couple other distinct applications.  On startup of the main/shell application, after determining who the user is, the main app will query the database to determine which sub-apps the user can use and build out the UI.  Then the user can navigate between available sub-apps and do their work in each.

I hope all this makes sense.

Anyway, I’m wondering which, if any, pre-existing technologies/frameworks would work best for architecting and developing a system such as this.

Would the Web Client Software Factory be a good choice?
Would some other MVP solution be a good choice?
Would ASP.NET MVC be a good choice?
Something else????
Would none of these be a good choice and we should just develop everything from the ground up using web forms?
Any other info I should know about?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Architecture Suggestions/Recommendations for a Web Application with Sub-Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719196/architecture-suggestions-recommendations-for-a-web-application-with-sub-apps)

Comment: Please stop posting duplicate questions.

Comment: I had some issue with the open id thing, so I thought I needed to re-post it (and, in doing so, I tried to clean-up and clarify the original post - so, technically, they are slightly different).  If I could delete the original post, I would.  But, I can't, or at least it's not clear at all how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net MVC2 also facilitates the use of areas.  Here is a link that may be useful

http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/10/13/asp-net-mvc2-preview-2-areas-and-routes.aspx

basically you could use areas to break out your "subapplications"

Answer (score 0):

Before discussing frameworks, some points to consider when building such a system (where sub-apps can be plugged in):

- Possible integration points (Data, Services, Business Logic, UI)
- Cross-cutting concerns (system logging, audit logging, config, security)
- Who'll be developing the sub-apps (you, people that work in your office, or anyone / the greater community)

I think that before leaping in and building a framework (or choosing an existing one) you need to step back and think through these aspects first.

In terms of farmeworks: you'll find many frameworks but very few offer the full range of what you're after:

- ASP.NET WebForms is basically a completely vacant parcel of land - you'll have to build most things yourself, or bring in additional frameworks (such as the MS Enterprise Libraries)
- ASP.NET MVC is effectively the same thing but in a different style.

Neither of these are "frameworks" but you could use either of these as the low-level base 'platform'.

- The MS Ent Libs are great for cross-cutting concerns (like data access, logging, etc) but that's all.
- There's also a range of good [Dependency Inversion frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582098/what-di-ioc-framework-should-i-learn-next) but again these aren't a full solution.

The big thing is to control dependencies: ensure you abstract out the data layer (for a start), adhere to principles around interface segregation, reuse and so on.

One option that you could consider (and I'm blowing my own trumpet here - so I'm not impartial) is  the open source .net application framework I've built ('[Morphfolia](http://www.morphological.geek.nz/Morphfolia/default.aspx)' it's taken me about 5 years, part-time). Even if you don't use it you might find some good ideas or code you can 'steal':

Morphfolia:

- [Architecture](http://www.morphological.geek.nz/Architecture/default.aspx)
- [Integration Options Overview](http://www.morphological.geek.nz/Morphfolia/Development/integrationguide.aspx)
- [Capabilities and Features (overview)](http://www.morphological.geek.nz/Morphfolia/Capabilities/default.aspx)
- [Attribute Driven](http://www.morphological.geek.nz/Morphfolia/Capabilities/AttributeDriven.aspx) (my answer to providing a plug-and-play architecture)

It's available for download at http://morphfolia.codeplex.com/